# Display a custom taxonomy of a product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, display, custom-taxonomy

I've create a custom taxonomy for my products in woocommerce. It's the not hierarchical taxonomy of the authors of my bookstore. The code for the taxonomy is this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_autor_nonhierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );
function create_autor_nonhierarchical_taxonomy() {
// Labels part for the GUI
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Autor', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Autor', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Buscar autores' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Autores populares' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'Todos los autores' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Editar autor' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Actualizar autor' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Añadir nuevo autor' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'Nombre del nuevo autor' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separa los autores con comas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Añadir o eliminar autores' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Elije ente los autores más utilizados' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Autor' ),
  ); 

// Now register the non-hierarchical taxonomy like tag

  register_taxonomy('autor','product',array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'autor' ),
  ));
}
```

Well, everything works perfectly but now I'm not able to display the author. I'm trying using the following code but it doesn't work (it displays only the word "array"):

```
echo '<span>De '.get_the_terms($post->ID ,'autor').'</span>';
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: :((( I'm lost. I've checked the WC_Post_types but I haven't found the code I'm looking for.

Comment: Oh yeah!!! Find out the solution: <span>De '.get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'autor').'</span>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using `get_the_term_list()` function instead:

```
echo '<span>De ' . get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'autor') . '</span>'
```